# Replace a value in a nested dictionary by following a certain path to value in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary that I'm trying to replace a given value of a key using a path made up of keys to that particular value.

Basic Example:

```
path_to_value = ["fruit", "apple", "colour"]

replacement_value = "green"

dictionary = {"fruit":  {"apple":   {"colour":  "red"}, "banana": {"colour": "yellow", "size": "big"}}}
```

I've found a function here on Stackoverflow, but it recursively replaces all values in the dict which I don't want.

```
def change_key(d, required_key, new_value):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            change_key(v, required_key, new_value)
        if k == required_key:
            d[k] = new_value
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this should work: narrow in using all but the last keys to get the dictionary you want to modify, then modify it using the last key.

```py
def change_key(d, path_to_value, new_value):
    for key in path_to_value[:-1]:
        d = d[key]
    d[path_to_value[-1]] = new_value
```

Answer (score 0):

you cay try this:

```
def replace_val(dict, val_path, new_val):
    if len(val_path) == 1:
        dict[val_path[0]] = new_val
        return dict
    else:
        dict[val_path[0]] = replace_val(dict[val_path[0]], val_path[1:], new_val)
        return dict
```

Comment: You should not override the built-in dict object (`d` or `a_dict` is preferred).